# highlight clicked div only

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code and i want to highlight the div clicked and not the others. I also want to get the data from an external page and load it into the target div...not sure how to add this part to the script. currently this is what i have.

php

```
<div id="targetdiv"></div>
  <div class="item">
for($id=0; $id<10; $id++){
    echo  '<div class="al-cover slides" id="img'.$id.'" >
               <img class="imgs" src="'.$mediapath.'" alt="" onclick="img('.$id.')" data-id="'.$id.'"/>';                           
           </div>';
}
</div>
```

javascript

```
var slideIndex = 1;

function img(index) {
  show(index);
}

function nextslide(index) {
  show(slideIndex += index);
}

function show(index) {

  // Get the container element
  var selextImg = document.getElementById("img" + index);

  $('.items').each(function() {
    numItems = $(this).find('.picks').length;
    selextImg.style.border = "solid 2px #3cba54";
  });
  if (index > numItems) {
    slideIndex = 1;
    index = 1;
  }
  if (index < 1) {
    slideIndex = numItems;
    index = numItems;
  }
  var path = $("#img" + index).find('img').attr('src');

  $("#targetdiv").html('<img src="' + path + '"  class="fit"/>');
}
```

Comment: Do you want the `#targetdiv` or the `.al-cover.slides` clicked? Have you tried adding a `click` event listener?

Comment: where are **.items** elements?

Comment: no the target div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the common class to all of the divs that should have the option to be highlighted

```
<div class="al-cover">...</div>
```

Add click event listener to the class(jquery example)

```
$(document).on('click', '.al-cover', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).prop('id'); //get the id of clicked div
    // use ajax request to fetch desired data
    $.ajax({
     url: '/urlToYourExternalPage',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {id: id},
     success: function( response ) {
         response = JSON.parse( response );
         // get the data from response
         // create the html from data
         var html = ....;
         // apend the html to target div
         $(this).append(html);  
     },
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log( xhr.responseText );
     }
   });
      });
```

Comment: error: is where i keep reaching. i am not getting a success response